# Deployment of Crystal Reports with ms access database as backend

Tags: ms-access, deployment, crystal-reports, subreport

I've created a Crystal Report project with MS Access DB backend on our development server in 1st. Step. The path is smth. like H:...\db\my.db. After compiling the project, I've deployed it on another Server and start it over mstsc.exe to open a remote session on it.It functions.
In step 2 I inserted a subreport with a data source in the same db and linked it with the main report over id field. Checked it on development server and copied to production one. Now, when I try to stat the report I'm prompted to log in and the Server and Db name are shown to be ones from development server.

Is there any way to set all reports data sources and links programmatically at the runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use integrated security?  Or did you want the connection's userID and password stored with the report?

Comment: I think this probably isn't the issue--I suspect the report (or the subreport) is trying to refer back to the dev server, which is NOT what the OP wants to happen even (especially!) transparently.